# Coin flipping with subsequent random report of the result

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A coin having probability .8 of landing on heads is flipped.
A observes the result either heads or tails and rushes off to tell
B. However, with probability .4, A will have forgotten the re-
sult by the time he reaches B. If A has forgotten, then, rather
than admitting this to B, he is equally likely to tell B that
the coin landed on heads or that it landed tails. (If he does
remember, then he tells B the correct result.)

`(a) What is the probability that B is told that the coin landed
on heads?`

`(b) What is the probability that B is told the correct result?`

`(c) Given that B is told that the coin landed on heads, what
is the probability that it did in fact land on heads?`

for (a)
 i did something like this :

P(b is told head)=P(head)xP(remember result)+P(make a guess)xP(forget the result)

```
            =0.8x0.6+0.5x0.4

            =0.68
```

i don't know how to solve (b) and (c) part and please correct (a) weather wrong or right.

Comment: Do you agree with the title I propose which is less "neutral" than the one you had chosen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result of the flip:

1. Heads (.8)

   A have forgotten:

   - Yes (.4)

     a) A tells "Heads" (.5) - result "Heads", true, $.8\cdot .4\cdot.5=.16$

     b) A tells "Tails" (.5) - result "Tails", false, $.8\cdot .4\cdot.5=.16$
   - No (.6) - result "Heads", true, $.8\cdot.6=.48$
2. Tails (.2)

   - Yes (.4)

     a) A tells "Tails" (.5) - result "Tails", true, $.2\cdot .4\cdot.5=.04$

     b) A tells "Heads" (.5) - result "Heads", false, $.2\cdot .4\cdot.5=.04$
   - No (.6) - result "Tails", true, $.2\cdot.6=.12$

To obtain "Heads" we have three paths with probabilities $.16, .48, .04$, so $$P(\text{"Heads"})=.16 + .48+ .04 = .68$$

To obtaint correct result we have 4 paths with probabilities $.16,.48,.04,.16$, so
$$P(\text{Correct result})=.16+.48+.04+.12=.80$$

If B was told "Heads" (with probability $.68$) we have 2 situations, that leads to "Heads" and correct result with probabilities $.16, .48$.
$$P(\text{"Heads" & correct result})=.16+.48=.64$$
So
$$P(\text{correct result if "Heads"})=\frac{P(\text{"Heads" & correct result})}{P(\text{"Heads"})}=\frac{.64}{.68}=\frac{16}{17}\approx .94 $$

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shown any effort to work out the problem yourself i will give you hints for the first part.

Probability that b is told that coin lands on head is the probability that coin lands on head given that a has not forgotten and probabilty that b has reported head given that b has forgotten.

Transform all this to mathematical equation you will reach the answer.